# Ajax navigation/browser back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

Need to implement ajax navigation without any page reload
I'm writing html to ajax container div.
Is there any solution to handle browser back and forward events. Also adding to a bookmark?
I need to cover all browser including IE 8 and higher. Thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear and separate your questions? Also, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)??

Comment: I have a html page with top menu links. On link click event I'm changing the ajax-container div with appropriate html content and changing the url in address bar with hostname#?page=blabla (using jQuery). With such implementation browser back and forward buttons doesn't fork (actually window.history.back also doesn't work) and I'm trying to find out the proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

The browser history is normally only updated when the browser loads a new page. AJAX doesn't replace the page, so the history is not changed.

HTML5 adds an API to allow Javascript to update the history directly, the `history.pushState()` and `history.replaceState()` methods. Your AJAX code should be able to use `pushState()` to add the old URL to the browser history, so the back button will work. See  [the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-history-pushstate) for the gory details.

Since this is relatively new, older browsers won't support it. You could use the [jQuery BBQ Plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) for cross-browser applications.